# Second Spacer in Column doesn't show up

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Why isn't the second Spacer shown up?

```
    Column(modifier = Modifier
        .size(400.dp)
        .offset(y = (-100).dp)
    ) {
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier
            .size(400.dp)
            .background(Color.Gray))
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier
            .size(400.dp)
            .background(Color.LightGray)
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier
            .size(400.dp)
            .background(Color.DarkGray))

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier
            .size(400.dp)
            .background(Color.Black))
    }
```

also i found that it will be show up after adding a `modifier.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())` to the parent Column and those last 3 Spacer all are placed in (0.0, 400.0) that got through `modifier.onGloballyPositioned()`

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! If the answer below was useful to you, please consider to upvote or accept it by clicking the checkmark at the left side of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

A [`Column`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/package-summary#Column(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement.Vertical,androidx.compose.ui.Alignment.Horizontal,kotlin.Function1)) by default lets each child sequentially take up all space it wants, unless the `weight` Modifier is applied:

> The `Column` layout is able to assign children heights according to their weights provided using the `ColumnScope.weight` modifier. If a child is not provided a weight, it will be asked for its preferred height before the sizes of the children with weights are calculated[...]

If you define the total size of the `Column` as `400.dp` and the first `Spacer` alone also is `400.dp` in size, then all `Spacer`s except the first one will not be visible.

If you want to make sure that all `Spacer`s are visible on the screen without scrolling, use the `weight` Modifier as follows:

```
Column(modifier = Modifier
    .size(400.dp)
) {
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier
        .weight(1f)
        .background(Color.Gray))
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier
        .weight(1f)
        .background(Color.LightGray))
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier
        .weight(1f)
        .background(Color.DarkGray))
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier
        .weight(1f)
        .background(Color.Black))
}
```

This will split the space evenly between the `Spacer`s. 
 Note that I also removed the negative offset, I think you only should use this if you know exactly what you are doing.